# Update state from another component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am trying to update state of page index in index.js from component Pagination,

my index.js:

```
import useSWR from 'swr';
import { useState } from 'react';

const Index = ({ data }) => {
    
    const initialStatePage = () => 1;

    const [pageIndex, setPageIndex] = useState(initialStatePage);

    const { data } = useSWR(`http://1.2.3.4/api/console?pagination[page]=${pageIndex}`, fetcher, {fallbackData: data});

  return (
<>
    <h1> {data} <h1/>
    <Pagination pagenow={initialStatePage}/>
<>
  );
};
export default Index;
```

my component:

```
import { useState } from 'react';

const Pagination = ({ pagenow }) => {
    const [pageIndex, setPageIndex] = useState(pagenow);
  return (
    <>
                    <li>
                      <button onClick={() => setPageIndex(pageIndex - 1)}>
                      </button>
                    </li>
                      <button onClick={() => setPageIndex(pageIndex + 1)}>
                      </button>
                    </li>
    </>
    )
};

export default Pagination;
```

but after click, page index is not updating from my component

Answer (score 0):

The state in your `Pagination` component will rerender the children element, not the whole page.
If you want it to rerender the whole `Index` page, pass your `setPageIndex` function to the component and use it to set the page index:

`index.js`

```js
import useSWR from 'swr';
import { useState } from 'react';

const Index = ({ data }) => {
    const initialStatePage = () => 1;

    const [pageIndex, setPageIndex] = useState(initialStatePage);
    const { data } = useSWR(`http://1.2.3.4/api/console?pagination[page]=${pageIndex}`, fetcher, {fallbackData: data});

    return <>
        <h1>{data}</h1>
        <Pagination pagenow={initialStatePage} setPageIndex={setPageIndex} />
    <>;
};
export default Index;
```

`Pagination component file`

```js
import { useState } from 'react';

const Pagination = ({ pagenow: pageIndex, setPageIndex }) => {
    return <>
        <li>
            <button onClick={() => setPageIndex(pageIndex - 1)}></button>
            <button onClick={() => setPageIndex(pageIndex + 1)}></button>
        </li>
    </>;
};

export default Pagination;
```